# what would be a proper storyboard example of combining nav bars and tab bars in one app?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

Hi I'm new to ios app dev. I've only done tutorials so far that have covered apps with either nav bars or tab bars. Now I want to make an app combining both.

So, say I have an app with a tab bar at the bottom with two tabs: friends and enemies. In each tab i plan to have a running list of who my friends and enemies are, so it will need an addPerson button on the nav bar of each tab.

given that scenario, what would be the proper way to organize my controllers and views and stuff? 
would both my tab controller and my nav controller be pointing to the same view controller?

i'm having trouble conceptualizing how my nav controller(2 nav controllers now?) would work in a more complex app.

Comment: I'm not using storyboard in my app, but I do have a tab/nav controller. I've got the tab controller as the root and then a nav controller inside each tab (well, the tabs that need one). I have a completely separate xib file for each tab.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how to set it up in your Storyboard.  The `TabBarController` is the main controller.  Each item of the `TabBarController` has its own `NavigationController`:

[image]

You probably want to use a `TableViewController` for your lists.  Here I have shown the `TableViewController` as the rootViewController of the `NavigationController`.

A quick way to construct this is to delete everything in the Storyboard and then drag out two `TableViewControllers` placing one directly above the other.  Select both by dragging an outline around them both, and then select `Editor->Embed In->Tab Bar Controller` from the menu.  Then select each `TableViewController` in turn and select `Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller`.

Comment: thanks for a clear answer. to any noobs in the future, make sure on the tab bar controller to have "is initial view controller" checked. it gets automatically deselected if you delete everything in the storyboard

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the title dynamically, use this function from your UITabBar delegate:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    self.title = viewController.title
    print("Should select viewController: \(viewController.title) ?")
    return true;
}
```

Then just set the viewControllers `title` in the view controller like you would normally do with a UINavigationBar.