# Have a NavigationController within a TabBarController Item

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I've looked around and been unable to find a clear example/explanation of how to do this. I've just started with swift, apologies if any terminology is off.

What I'm looking to do is **add a NavigationController to one of my TabBarItems in a way that I can view multiple views from utilizing the NavigationController while still staying within that TabBarItem view**

So far I have the TabBar created, with three items. I don't mind doing it in either storyboard or programatically.

Comment: I'm not at a computer right now so I can't test it. But have you tried in the storyboard giving each page view controller it's own navigation controller and making the navigation controllers the view controllers pointed to by the tab bar controller?

Comment: Here's the Storyboard example:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26153273/1630618

Comment: In storyboard, create your scene, embed that in a Navigation controller then embed the navigation controller in a tab controller  - pretty straightforward.  In code create ViewController, set it as the root of navigation controller and then add the navigation controller to a tab bar controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the storyboard give each page view controller it's own navigation controller and make the navigation controllers the view controllers pointed to by the tab bar controller.
Do it like so:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26153273/1527064
[image: navigation controllers with tab bar controller]