# How to set title of Navigation Bar in Swift?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to set title of `Navigation Bar` in Swift, I set `Tab Bar` and in `Navigation Bar` nothing is showing, no button, no title, nothing. I used some code but it's not working while I use `Tab Bar`, and when I deleted `Tab Bar`, code is working and everything is ok with `Navigation Bar`, title is showing and buttons are showing.

Code that I used for title is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.title = "My Title"

}
```

And in `Main.storyboard` I connected `Navigation Controller` with `Tab Bar Controller`, as in picture.

[image]

So, how to fix this ? The problem is that `Navigation Bar` is not working while using `Tab Bar`.

Comment: You have the navigation controller and the tab bar controller the wrong way around. The tab bar should be the root. Then each tab should have a navigation controller. This will give you the standard controls that come with a tab bar and setting the title will be easier.

Comment: When combining tab bar controllers and navigation controllers, the root controller should be a tab bar controller and each tab should have its own nav controller. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26153273/1630618

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since the `Tab Bar` is actually the `Root View Controller` of the `Navigation Bar`, you need to set the `UITabBarController`'s `title` instead in the `viewWillAppear` function so that it happens every time you switch tabs:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "My Title"
    self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = settingsButton //This is the IBOutlet variable that you previously added
}
```

But a better way to do it would actually be to have it the other way around, like so

[image: Correct view hierarchy]

You should hook up a `UINavigationController` for each child of the `UITabBarController`, as it is more correct semantically, and simpler to maintain.

Comment: And how about buttons ?

Comment: Create an `IBOutlet` for each button, and use the code that I am just going to update my answer with

Comment: @EminEmini the actual problem though is that you should technically have the `UINavigationController` inside the `UITabBarController` instead of the other way around

Comment: Ya it's working but there is problem, When I go to second or third tab, and when I go back to 1st or 2nd title won't change.

Comment: @EminEmini have you removed the old code?

Comment: @EminEmini also, if you have, please could you update the screenshot in your question?

Comment: @EminEmini I fixed it. See my updated answer.

Comment: Both ways are working. Thanks bro.

Comment: @EminEmini no problem :) btw I recommend using the second one, as it is easier to use

Answer (score 10):

Your question is unclear, if the code you presented is from `UIViewController` that is kept inside `UINavigationController` and `navigationBar` is shown you can simply use:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "My Title"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In *UINavigationController Class Reference* Apple wrote this:

> init(rootViewController: UIViewController)
>   Parameters
>   rootViewController
>   The view controller that resides at the bottom of the navigation stack. This object cannot be an instance of the UITabBarController class.

But you can do it if you insisted.But in this case , your ViewControllers of tabbarController all shared the same title,which is the title of tabbarController.

A better way to do it is to give each of tabbarController's viewControllers a NavigationViewController.