# iOS-swift navigation controller not styling correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I got the following issue with my code:

On my App i have a navigationController and I style the bar accordingly to the viewcontroller i´m presenting with this function:

```
func styleNavBar(barColor: String){

    let logo = UIImage(named: "logo-sura.pdf")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
    self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView

    switch barColor {
    case "Dark":
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        return
    case "Light":
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(netHex: 0x1CBBE1)
        return
    default:
        return
    }
}
```

It works just as intended on the bottom viewcontrollers (which are presented via segue) -i attached an image- [Story board that shows teh viewcontroller flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRyWq.jpg) but on the ones that have the tabBar associated it wont present the logo or navigation ítems.

Any pointer of what am i missing.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your storyboard I would suggest to do the following:

1. Instantiate your tabbar controller and present it.
2. Embed each tabbar child view controllers in a navigation controller. As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33707512/how-to-set-title-of-navigation-bar-in-swift)

Your storyboard will look like this:

[image]

To present the tabbar controller:

```
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! UITabBarController
        self.presentViewController(tabBarController,animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
```

Then in your child vc's

```
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let logo = UIImage(named: "logo")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
        self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView

    }
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: It does show but it wont let me apply the logo with the     **self.navigationItem.titleView** method

Comment: can you show me the view controller flow starting from the tabbar?